# Laravel hasManyThrough manipulates user_id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, has-many-through

I got problems with the hasManyThrough function in Laravel.

My goal is to get a feed where the posts show up by users that the logged in user follows. I try to achieve this by:

1. In User.php, get the ID of the logged in user
2. Match the user's id with the columns called user_id in Follow.php
3. Get the target_id from the rows in Follow.php
4. Get the posts where user_id matches the target_ids from Follow.php

I retrieve the data correctly by who the user follows. However, the user_id that gets returned in the data is the logged in user and not the author of the post. Why?

**User.php**

```
public function feed() {
return $this->hasManyThrough(
       'App\Post',
       'App\Follow',
       'user_id',
       'user_id',
       'id',
       'target_id'
)
->with('user')
->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}
```

**Post.php**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Called from controller via**

```
$posts = Auth::user()->feed;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code creates this query: `` select `posts`.*, `follows`.`user_id`... ``

As you can see, `posts.user_id` gets overwritten by `follows.user_id` (`follows.user_id` is necessary for eager loading).

I see two possible solutions for your problem:

1. Rename `follows.user_id`.
2. Use two separate relationships: `User` → `HasMany` → `Follow` → `HasMany` → `Post`